# How to pass data from DataContext to ListBox in WPF?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I have a class defined like:

```
public class Agent 
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public string Category { get; set; }

    // rest removed for brevity 
}
```

Then, in WPF, I get the data as `List` and pass it to `DataContext` as this:

```
List<Agent> agents; // this includes my data
this.DataContext = agents;
```

And in `.xaml` part I want to list the `Category` field of each object. I have something like this:

```
<ListBox
    Name="agentCategoryListBox"
    Grid.Row="2"
    Grid.Column="1"
    ItemSource="{Binding Path=Category"} />
```

But this doesn't seem to work correctly. Any ideas?

Comment: what orm u are using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let me help you to do this in the correct way as Alex suggested.

Create a list and populate it in ViewModel like this

> ViewModel

```
public class MainWindowViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {

        public MainWindowViewModel()
        {
            agents = new ObservableCollection<Agent>();
            LoadData();
        } 


    private void LoadData()
        {            
            agents.Add(new Agent { Id = 1, Category = "a" });
            agents.Add(new Agent { Id = 2, Category = "b" });
            agents.Add(new Agent { Id = 3, Category = "c" });
        }
    }
```

In XAML, Make your list and use data template like this:

```
    <Window.Resources>
        <DataTemplate x:Key="AItemTemplate">
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Category}"></TextBlock>
        </DataTemplate>
    </Window.Resources>

<ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding agents}" 
         ItemTemplate="{StaticResource AItemTemplate}"></ListBox>
```

That is it !!

Answer (score 1):

Normally the DataContext would be a view model class that would **contain** the list of agents; then you can bind the ItemsSource to that list. Any of the many examples that deal with listbox will be pretty straight forward when it comes to that. Not really sure how the binding should look like if the list itself is the DataContext.

Then once the ItemsSource is set to a list of agents, if you want to show the Category in the list, the simpler way is to set DisplayMemberPath to "Category".

I suggest looking into MVVM and learning to apply it, it's an invaluable concept in my opinion.

Answer (score 0):

I also would suggest you to use MVVM. But if you do not want to then try this.

XAML:

```
<ListBox Name="AgentCategoryListBox" ItemsSource="{Binding}">
  <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
      <TextBlock Text="{Binding Category}" d:DataContext="{d:DesignData}" />
    </DataTemplate>
  </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
```

CS:

```
public MainWindow()
{
  InitializeComponent();

  List<Agent> agents = new List<Agent>
  {
    new Agent
    {
      Category = "Category"
    }
  };

  DataContext = agents;
}

public class Agent
{
  public string Category
  {
    get;
    set;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You try to bind your listbox to a string property.

You can try this :
Give a name to your user control for exemle myUC
Add a property to your user control :

```
 public List<Agent> AgentList { get; set; };
```

Fill your agentlist :

```
this.AgentList = //fill method
```

And bind your listbox like this :

```
<ListBox
Name="agentCategoryListBox"
Grid.Row="2"
Grid.Column="1"
ItemSource="{Binding Path=AgentList, ElementName=myUC"} />
```

Comment: I think this is unecessarily complicated and distracts from the 'right' way, which is MVVM and which would me more helpful going forward. In my opinion :)

Answer (score 0):

may be this will give you an idea:

> http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/forums/wpf-datacontext-binding-with-listbox

Answer (score 0):

The fastest way to get what you want is :

```
<ListBox
    Name="agentCategoryListBox"
    Grid.Row="2"
    DisplayMemberPath="Category"
    Grid.Column="1"
    ItemSource="{Binding Path=."} />
```

ItemsSource is binded directly to your Datacontext (which is your list) And then you tell to your ListBox to display the property Category.

But the proper way would have been :

1 - Create a DataContext

```
public class AgentsDC
{
    public List<Agent> Agents { get; set; }
}
```

2 - Give this class as DataContext

```
this.DataContext = new AgentsDC();
```

3 - Bind all these things

```
<ListBox
    Name="agentCategoryListBox"
    Grid.Row="2"
    DisplayMemberPath="Category"
    Grid.Column="1"
    ItemSource="{Binding Path=Agents"} />
```